# Excel::Writer::XLSX using numbers as hyperlinks

Tags: perl

Need create an Excel file where in some cells has `numbers` and these numbers should be as labels for the hyperlink.

So, using the following demo code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'test.xlsx' );
my $f_url = $workbook->add_format( color => 'blue', underline => 1 );
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

my $url = 'http://example.com/aaa=';
my $num = 123;

$worksheet->write_url( 0, 0, $url.$num, $f_url, $num );

$workbook->close();
```

After opening the `test.xlsx` in the Excel, it shows an cell-warning about the `number stored as text`, like in the following screenshot:

[image]

after selecting the `convert to number` got:

[image]

E.g. correct hyperlink, where the "number" is really number (right aligned, without warning).

The question is: how to create the `test.xlsx` to get an correct cell type? e.g. `number` **and** `hyperlink`?

The [Excel::Writer::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX#write_number-row-column-number-format) knows:

```
write_string()
write_number()
write_blank()
write_formula()
write_url()
write_row()
write_col()
```

but the `write_url` (used in the example) produces "text" and not a number type cell.

Is here some workaround to create the correct `xlsx` without warnings?

Answer (score 1):

Just need more precisely read the doc. It says:

> If you wish to have some other cell data such as a number or a formula
>   you can overwrite the cell using another call to write_*():

So, the solution is using:

```
$worksheet->write_url( 0, 0, $url.$num, $f_url, $num );
# adding another write after the write_url - the link remains
$worksheet->write_number( 0, 0, $num, $f_url ); # and now it is an number
```